# how to manage adding files to entities in symfony

Tags: forms, symfony

i am trying to add multiple files to an entity.i want to get users the possibility to upload from PC or add existing files from server to this entity.
the question is how to manage that? on create and edit the entity ? is it possible to mix data transformers and form events on a single field?the entity of file can be added to multiple entities and each entity has multiple files

Answer (score 0):

Handling file uploads in Symfony natively without the help of any other components is a bit messy in my opinion, but it's possible. Take a look at [this cookbook article](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/file_uploads.html).

However, I suggest you take a look at the [VichUploaderBundle](https://github.com/dustin10/VichUploaderBundle) community bundle